# electron can't use bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, electron

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TJ3w.png)

Failed to execute 'requestDevice' on 'Bluetooth': Must be handling a user gesture to show a permission request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

requestDevice cannot be triggered without the user doing an action to prompt the request. See: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devices